# How can I print which keys are pressed?

Tags: c#, hotkeys

Mostly every program that uses hotkeys allows the user to see which keys are actually being pressed, but I'm not sure how it is accomplished. For reference, see the following screenshot of a random program that captures what the button combination is:

[image]

How can I implement something like this? The event I'm reading from is of Type `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs`. There are many keys which have no description of its actual value and several others which have inaccurate values. Is there no solution outside of finding out the code for each key and displaying them manually?

Edit: For clarification, I want to get a user friendly string representation of the keys that were pressed as shown in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event has bool properties for `Alt`, `Control` and `Shift`.

`KeyCode`'s type is [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx). It has a `[Flags]` attribute, but that only counts for `Alt`, `Control` and `Shift`. All other keys have a *regular* value.

```cs
private void showKeys(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    if (e.Control == true)
    {
        keys.Add("CTRL");
    }

    if (e.Alt == true)
    {
        keys.Add("ALT");
    }

    if (e.Shift == true)
    {
        keys.Add("SHIFT");
    }

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.ControlKey:
        case Keys.Alt:
        case Keys.ShiftKey:
        case Keys.Menu:
            break;
        default:
            keys.Add(e.KeyCode.ToString()
                .Replace("Oem", string.Empty)
                );
            break;
    }

    e.Handled = true;

    textBox1.Text = string.Join(" + ", keys);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I want to print a user friendly string that indicates which keys were pressed. Have you taken a look at the example in the question? I don't need to enumerate through multiple keys since I will only be allowing modifier(s) and one other key.

Comment: Well, you have all required data available. You still need to do some of the work. I've edited the answer to include sample code. In the case of `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` the `KeyCode` property will only hold one value, so depending on the way you handle the event it could need some modification.

Comment: There may be some edge cases you need to handle, for example the *Oem...* keys. Go over the `Keys` enum to see if there are any additional cases you wish to handle.

Comment: Something seems off. This is what I'm getting when I press "5" (NOT numpad) http://i.imgur.com/qm2729X.png I've tried pressing regular characters, but none of them actually translate what the key I pressed is in any of the fields, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: I had a look at the Enum and it turns out this is a bit of a weird one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162110/system-windows-forms-keys-hasflag-behaving-weirdly explains it. Summary: Alt, Control and Shift behave as flag values, all other keys should be seen as single values. `D5 = 53` or `110101` is the expected result, however, due to the `[Flags]` attribute, you see `LButton = 1, MButton = 4, ShiftKey = 16, Space = 32` or `110101`. http://i.imgur.com/x0c3bO5.png

Comment: Thanks for finding an explanation on that. Let me look into the other keys when I have some time and I'll get back to you. Have an upvote for now.

Comment: Ok, so I tried actually printing the value and it shows up properly. I was a bit thrown off by the values shown by the debugger. I'll accept your answer since it explained why I wasn't seeing the actual representation.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyEventArgs.KeyCode Property....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx)

if u can use javascript u will have a code for each key

[Keycodes in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/full-list-of-javascript-keycodes)

and i found this quite interesting for  Keyeventargs.Keycode 
http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get witch key pressed by this code(for single key or multiple key pressed,set form KeyPreview to true )

```
    private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = null;
        label1.Text=e.Modifiers.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned that the event is `KeyEventArgs`, not `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

For a win-form, you need firstly to set property [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) to `true`. That way, the pressed key should be detected, even if one of the form's childs has the focus and form itself doesn't have it.

Then,override one of the following methods: [`OnKeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeyup.aspx), [`OnKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown.aspx), and [`OnKeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress.aspx).

```
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.KeyCode)
  {
      case Keys.F1:
         showHelpTopics();
         break;
  }
}
```

If you suffer no description of some keys, just perform a msdn search and you will find its details.

Comment: I am globally detecting keystrokes so I don't think the KeyPreview property is relevant. Perhaps I should've mentioned that in the question.  In any case, I want to be able to handle all of the keys possible, so it would be inefficient to do something like a switch statement with all the possible scenarios.