# ProcessCmdKey - Keys.Tab == Keys.D9?

Tags: winforms

I have a form with a textbox on it. Inside the form I am overriding the ProcessCmdKey method:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Tab))
        Debugger.Break();

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

When I type 9 into the box, ProcessCmdKey sets keyData to 'D9'.

When the check to see if 'keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Tab)' is made the debugger breaks.

[image]

Why is Keys.HasFlag returning true when keyData is not Keys.Tab? How can I get around this?

Comment: How can I detect the SHIFT key being pressed if I do that?

Comment: Also, if you look at the msdn for Keys it is marked with the FlagsAttribute and so it is a flag. https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Keys);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: `if (keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab))`  This will detect Shift and the Tab keys being pressed.  Your question didn't mention anything about a shift key.

Comment: I know that works but any idea why HasFlag is acting this way?

Comment: See [System.Windows.Forms.Keys.HasFlag behaving weirdly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162491/719186)

Comment: Good ol' Hans. Thanks for the link.